# Word 2016 color selection drop down not working

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

The font selection and and the size both work. It is Office 2016 installed on windows 10 x64. Using word automatic repair did not work, what else could be causing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the whole "don't work" description. How do they not work? They are disabled, when you click they won't do what is expected, what happens?

Comment: when I click on any of them they do not drop down it acts like it is disabled (but it is not) and it does not show anything like you would expect it to. This is on a deployment of multiple computers and some have the issue and some don't but they were all made from the same image and I have loged in as admin and non admin users and they both have the same issue, nether user has a roaming profile.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'preselect' a color for text you haven't typed yet (but you *can* preselect font and size).
Type something and select it, and you'll be able to change the color.

Comment: Even if I type stuff I still can't change color

Answer (score 0):

The person that told me that the repair does not work was not explaining it well in the end the the self repair worked